# GrADS -- libssl.so.10: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: 16.04, openssl

I have installed [GrADS](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/) on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS system (x86_64) and after following all the INSTALL steps, I am getting the following error in my terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/grads: error while loading shared libraries:
libssl.so.10: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

What have done wrong? I definitely have OpenSSL installed on my system.

Comment: From what archive you have installed the application - [grads-2.2.0-bin-i686-pc-linux-noSSL-gnu.tar.gz](ftp://cola.gmu.edu/grads/2.2/grads-2.2.0-bin-i686-pc-linux-noSSL-gnu.tar.gz) or [grads-2.2.0-bin-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz](ftp://cola.gmu.edu/grads/2.2/grads-2.2.0-bin-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz)? Do you really need version 2.2.0 (or 2.2.1)? Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [has 2.0.2 in official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=grads).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have determined why I was having so many issues installing the latest version of GrADS (v2.2.1) the other day... My system is 64-bit and I was trying to install the 32-bit version... Doh!

Here are the commands that I used for v2.2.1:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/grads      
wget ftp://cola.gmu.edu/grads/data2.tar.gz      
tar -zxvf data2.tar.gz     
cd       
clear       
wget ftp://cola.gmu.edu/grads/Supplibs/2.2/builds/supplibs-centos7.4-x86_64.tar.gz      
tar -zxvf supplibs-centos7.4-x86_64.tar.gz     
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev libjpeg62-dev libgeotiff-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev    
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev libjpeg62-dev libgeotiff-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/grads/supplibs/libpng15.so.15 /usr/lib/   
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/grads/supplibs/libhdf5.so.8 /usr/lib/   
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/grads/supplibs/libnetcdf.so.7 /usr/lib/   
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/grads/supplibs/libhdf5_hl.so.8 /usr/lib/   
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/grads/supplibs/libtiff.so.3 /usr/lib/   
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/grads/supplibs/libgeotiff.so /usr/lib/   
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10   
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```